# Comparing integers to return Boolean in BigQuery

Tags: command-line, google-bigquery, type-conversion

Running a big query Select Case When query from the command line. When looking in a string, for a numeric value and casting that to an integer - this needs to be compared to a value and return a boolean so that the case statement worked.

```
bq query SELECT case when integer(right(strWithNumb,8))> 10000000 then right(strWithNumb,8) else "no" end FROM [Project:bucket.mytable]
```

returned

> "CASE expects the WHEN expression to be boolean."

I tried:

```
boolean(integer(right(strWithNumb,8))> 10000000)
```

but got

> " Was expecting: "WHEN" ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your original query works in Web UI - it DOES fail in bq command line tool depends on your environment - for example if you are on PC

Try to escape `>` character with `^` and embrace whole query with `"` as it is in example below. Please note also escaping of `"` in `"no"`

```
bq query "SELECT case when integer(right(strWithNumb,8)) ^> 10000000 then right(strWithNumb,8) else \"no\" end FROM [Project:bucket.mytable]"
```

you can avoid later by changing `"` to `'`

```
bq query "SELECT case when integer(right(strWithNumb,8)) ^> 10000000 then right(strWithNumb,8) else 'no' end FROM [Project:bucket.mytable]"
```

A little more explanations:

when you execute your original command (on PC for example via Google Cloud SDK Shell) your actual query becomes as below

```
SELECT case when integer(right(strWithNumb,8)) then right(strWithNumb,8) else "no" end FROM [Project:bucket.mytable]
```

As you can see your `> 10000000` part of query gets lost thus making `WHEN` expression `INTEGER` instead of expected `BOOLEAN`

Hope this helped